# Component not rerendering after setState in .then after Axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

In the code below, I want the `ListItem` component to refresh on `handleOnAdd` and `handleOnUpdate`.

These functions get passed as props to the `AddItem` and `EditItem` components.

The `ListItem` component gets its `item`s from `App`'s state.

It works fine for `handleOnDelete`, because I added `.then(this.handleChange())`. I do the same thing for `handleOnAdd` and `handleOnUpdate`, but those do not trigger a reload....

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [{ "_id": { "$oid": "5f1fda0169e133382277a4ef" }, "title": "Blabla", "description": "adfadfd211233", "__v": 0 }]
    }

    this.handleOnUpdate = this.handleOnUpdate.bind(this);
    this.handleOnAdd = this.handleOnAdd.bind(this);
    this.handleOnDelete = this.handleOnDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:4200/items')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ items: res.data })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  handleChange() {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:4200/items')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ items: res.data })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })

  }

  handleOnAdd(item) {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:4200/items/add/', item)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .then(this.handleChange());
  }

  handleOnUpdate(id, item) {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:4200/items/update/' + id, item)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .then(this.handleChange());

  }

  handleOnDelete(id) {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:4200/items/delete/' + id)
      .catch(err => console.log(err)).then(this.handleChange());
  }

  render() {
    return (
        .... Router stuff....
        <Route exact path='/add' render={(props) => <AddItem {...props} handleOnAdd={(item) => this.handleOnAdd(item)} />} />
        <Route path='/edit/:id' render={(props) => <EditItem {...props} handleOnUpdate={(id, item) => this.handleOnUpdate(id, item)} />} />
        <Route path='/index' render={(props) => <ListItem {...props} handleOnDeleteInApp={(id) => this.handleOnDelete(id)} items={this.state.items} />} />
        .... Router stuff....

    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone spot why `handleOnDelete` and the consequent state change succesfully triggers a rerender of `ListItem`, but the other functions don't?

Comment: How does your addItem look ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.then(this.handleChange());
```

This code calls `handleChange` *immediately*, and then pass its result into `.then`. So this code is not waiting for the add/update/delete on the previous lines. If `handleOnDelete` is working, then i think that's only due to a race condition.

You should change this line in all three functions to:

```
.then(() => this.handleChange())
```

or

```
.then(this.handleChange);
```